# Performance tool for MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, performance

Ciao, 
I'm looking for performance tool for testing of load in terms of data and number of users,better if they are open source

Thanks

Andrea

Answer (score 2):

In linux: [mytop](http://jeremy.zawodny.com/mysql/mytop/)

> "mytop is a console-based (non-gui) tool for monitoring the threads and overall performance of MySQL"

Ps:  It's open source

Comment: Seems like mytop doesn't support mysql 5.0 yet. Any news on if/when it will support it?

Comment: it seems to work in mysql 5.0 (i've just tried).

Answer (score 2):

I liked [monyog](http://www.webyog.com) though it was slightly buggy when it first got out of beta-testing.

Comment: An individual attempt to clear out this answer and post to the effect "Monyog is awesome now", that's not going to fly.  That said I did end up using monyog in 2011 and it had been steadily improved since my experiences in 2008-2009 and can be a good stop gap measure until a dedicated DBA would be required to keep the lights on.

Answer (score 0):

Check [Spotlight](http://www.quest.com/spotlight-on-mysql/). It's have a powerful tool

and see this [page it have a bunch of powerful tools](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/tools/)

Answer (score 0):

For diagnose performance problems you can use free [MySQL Query Profiler](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/using-new-query-profiler.html).